# Using a certificate in chrome without pvt key exportable to local computer

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate

is it possible in google chrome to use a certificate that is under local computer (in mmc) and not under local user? Basically I saw that chrome only retrieves certificates under local user.

I cannot load it manually as it is configured in mmc and does not have the exportable private key.

Thanks